# Store variable into array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

How to store the javascript variable into array?

I have these variable and I wish to store them into array:

```
var name=document.forms["form"]["name"].value;
    var email=document.forms["form"]["email"].value;
    var mobile=document.forms["form"]["mobile"].value;
    var q1=document.forms["form"]["q1"].value;
    var q2=document.forms["form"]["q2"].value;
    var q3=document.forms["form"]["q3"].value;
    var l1=document.forms["form"]["logo1"].value;
    var l2=document.forms["form"]["logo2"].value;
    var l3=document.forms["form"]["logo3"].value;
    var p1=document.forms["form"]["photo1"].value;
    var p2=document.forms["form"]["photo2"].value;
    var p3=document.forms["form"]["photo3"].value;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var arr = [];
var name=document.forms["form"]["name"].value;
var email=document.forms["form"]["email"].value;
arr.push(name);
//etc
```

Using the [**.push()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method

You could also serialize if you are going to post the form.

Comment: is it like that: var arr = [];
var name=document.forms["form"]["name"].value;
arr.push(name);var name=document.forms["form"]["email"].value;
arr.push(email);

Comment: @youaremysunshine, that would work but you can keep your var names and push that name. What do you want to do with those values?

Comment: @youaremysunshine, than you don't need this. If those are inputs you can use php to get the values.

Comment: Sorry for that Im just start to learning on these coding work

Comment: @youaremysunshine post your html and I can answer more specific. Otherwise use `$_POST['inputName']` in php to get the values

Comment: oh actually im doing this cz i wanna use ajax to run my php page on background

Comment: @youaremysunshine, sure. Do you use jQuery, Mootools or other library?

Comment: my example of ajax $.ajax({//to run exec in background
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'submit-exec.php',
   data: {'type':w, 'store_name':x, 'country':y, 'location':z},
   success: function(){
    $('.lightoff').css({ 'display': 'block'});
    $('.thankyou-wrapper').css({'display': 'block'});
    $('.genki').css({'display':'none'});
   
    } as u can see in the data part i need to post my variable tht is why i wanna to store my input text into javascript variable

Comment: @youaremysunshine, looks good, just use `data: form.serialize(),` and do the rest in php.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as

```
var newArray = [];
newArray[0] = name;
newArray[1] = email;

...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with traditional array:

```
var myArray = [];
myArray.push(document.forms["form"]["name"].value);
```

The keys will be numeric (starting from 0).
Or, if you want to preserve string keys, like *associative arrays* in other languages, you can store your values as an object

```
var myArray = {};
myArray["name"] = document.forms["form"]["name"].value;
```